# Try to connect a sftp server with ssh2 but the script runs forever without any error

Tags: php, sftp, libssh2

I try to connect to an sftp server using ssh2 but it seems that php get stuck in a loop.
Error reporting is on.

**my code:**

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('my-server.url', 22);
var_dump($connection);
if (ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password'))
{
    echo "Authentication success";
    if( ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "/throw_me_an_error/", "/somewhere/" ) )
    {
        echo "file recived";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo "Authentication failure";
}
```

**generate this output:**

```
resource(7) of type (SSH2 Session)
Authentication success
```

But as soon as the script tries to run ssh2_scp_recv it got stucked and runs forever without any failure. I tried it with existing and with non existing files. Every time the same result - the script runs in a loop.

It is not only ssh2_scp_recv even if i try ssh2_exec or some other method whichs need to write or read on the server, it will get stucked.

Whats going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have more luck with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Cool, i did not know of this. Does this pure PHP ssh really work? How is the performance compared to the extension?

Comment: I've used it successfully quite a few times.  And http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16925#comment:7 implies that it's actually faster than libssh2 although I think that somewhat depends on your network topology too.  Maybe phpseclib is faster at transferring to remote servers and libssh2 faster at transferring to local ones.  Or maybe phpseclib is faster all round - dunno!